# How would I go about assigning a keyframe to my selected bone? (in python)

Tags: python, armature, bones

How would I retrieve the "selected_bone" in pose mode and add a keyframe to my current timeline position using python?

I'm struggling to find the correct naming for "selected bone"

Answer (score 4):

**`context.active_pose_bone`**

Working from context (aka as `C` in python console) The active bone is `context.active_pose_bone`

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Armature']

>>> pb = C.active_pose_bone
>>> pb
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones["Bone"]
```

There can be more than one selected, these return lists. ***TIP** the python console has auto complete, those below are a set of options shown by typing `C.sel`<kbd>TAB</kbd> *ie* all properties of context starting with "sel".*

```
>>> C.selected_pose_bones
[bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones["Bone"]]

>>> C.selected_pose_bones_from_active_object
[bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones["Bone"]]
```

**Keyframing.**

Currently on frame 1

```
>>> C.scene.frame_current
1
```

Set the pose bone location, and a keyframe for x, y, and z location. True indicates the keyframe has been inserted successfully.

```
>>> pb.location = (1, 0, 0)
>>> pb.keyframe_insert("location")
True
```

set the location and keyframe for frame 10

```
>>> pb.location = (3, 0, 0)
>>> pb.keyframe_insert('location', frame=10)
True
```

only the z location, z is index 2 in "xyz"

```
>>> pb.keyframe_insert("location", index=2, frame=10)
True
```